# is there a way to change what image shows in a sidebox depending on the language of the page in zen cart?

Tags: php, zen-cart

I want to show a different image in the sidebox depedning on if the user is on the spanish site or english site is this possible? 
I have knowledge of php and i do not mind editing code if neccessary.

Answer (score 4):

There are three session variable that is used for manipulating current language in zencart

Default values :

[language] => english

[languages_id] => 1

[languages_code] => en

Above value update as per user language selection. You can write/update code in sidebox.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['languages_code']=='en')
{
   $image = 'your image path';
}
else if($_SESSION['languages_code']=='gr')
{
   $image = 'your image path';
}
else
{
   $image = 'your image path';
}
?>
```

Comment: you need to change side box template!!

Answer (score 0):

Following is way that you can manage the ,

In your template file add the following

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
   <div id="language">
        &nbsp;<img onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'en').submit(); $(this).parent().parent().submit();" title="English" alt="English" src="eng.png">
        &nbsp;<img onclick="$('input[name=\'language_code\']').attr('value', 'es').submit(); $(this).parent().parent().submit();" title="Spanish" alt="Spanish" src="spanish.png">
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="language_code">
    </div>
   </form>
```

following is the php code ,

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['language_code']))
    {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = ($_POST['language_code']!="")?$_POST['language_code']:"";
    }
    $language = $_SESSION['lang'];
    switch($language){
    case "en":
        //Your Image path
    break;
    default:
        //Your Image path
    break;
    }

    ?>
```